# Expectation Integral with 1/0

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

I am trying to show an expectation integral of a function diverges because it can take on the undefined value of $\frac{n}{0}$. When $n$ i.i.d. draws from $N(\theta,1)$ all equal $0$, which happens with some probability, my function $\frac{n}{\sum X_i}$ equals $\frac{n}{0}$ which is undefined. Since the probability of drawing all $0$s goes to $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity, I am not sure how I can use this to show my expectation integral does not exist. In the $n=1$ case I would show the limit as $X_1$ approaches $0$ is infinite, can I do the same in multiple dimensions? Is it sufficient to just show the $n=1$ case?

Comment: I don´t understand what "*...all n equal 0, ...*" means.

Comment: The $n$ i.i.d. draws all equal $0$. Typo sorry.

Comment: So every sample is equal to $0$? If so, then my first questions which comes in mind is: Is that possible?

Comment: I am trying to say that drawing $n$ consecutive $0$s is possible, which makes the function I want to find the expectation of undefined with some probability.

Comment: The choice of "exactly" $0$ occurs with technical measure $0$... *never* occurs.  Likewise, of course, multiple such selections.  This is a degenerate case that can—and should—be ignored.

Comment: Do you want to find the expectation of $1/\bar X$?

Comment: I don´t think that drawing an exact number is possible since the normal distribution is $\textrm{continuous}$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Yes

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In the $n=1$ case, $\Pr[X_1 = 0] = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\theta)^2} > 0$. Wouldn't the probability of $n$ consecutive $0$ draws be this probability raised to $n$ which is also non-zero?

Comment: @taurus.  No no no.  The probability *density* at $x=0$ is given by the Gaussian density function but the (finite) *probability* is defined for a *range* of values of $x$:  $$P[-\epsilon \leq x \leq +\epsilon] = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int\limits_{0 - \epsilon}^{0+\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x^2/2}\ dx = 0$$